# Text component overlapping with the View above it

Tags: react-native, layout

I'm practicing some react native code and I'm currently stuck with an overlapping problem.I've got this custom component:

```js
const MobileNumberInput = ({ value, valueChanged, placeholder, valid }) => {
  return (
    <View style={{ flexDirection: "row", flex: 1 }}>
      <TextInput
        editable={false}
        style={[styles.textBoxCountryCode, !valid ? styles.invalidTextBox : ""]}
        value="+90"
      />
      <TextInput
        style={[styles.textBoxPhoneNumber, !valid ? styles.invalidTextBox : ""]}
        placeholder={placeholder}
        value={value}
        onChangeText={valueChanged}
        keyboardType="number-pad"
        maxLength={9}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
export default MobileNumberInput;

onst styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    flex: 1,
    height: 40
  },
  textBoxCountryCode: {
    height: 40,
    borderColor: "gray",
    borderTopWidth: 1,
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderLeftWidth: 1,
    borderTopLeftRadius: 5,
    borderBottomLeftRadius: 5,
    padding: 5,
    flex: 2
  },
  textBoxPhoneNumber: {
    height: 40,
    borderColor: "gray",
    borderTopWidth: 1,
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderRightWidth: 1,
    borderTopRightRadius: 5,
    borderBottomRightRadius: 5,
    paddingTop: 5,
    paddingRight: 5,
    paddingBottom: 5,
    marginBottom: 10,
    flex: 11
  },
  invalidTextBox: {
    borderColor: "red"
  }
});
```

And here, I'm using that component:

```js
renderError = id => {
    const { validationErrors } = this.state;
    if (validationErrors[id]) {
      return (
        <Text style={styles.validationError}>{validationErrors[id][0]}</Text>
      );
    }
    return null;
  };
  render() {
    const keyboardVerticalOffset = Platform.OS === "ios" ? 40 : 0;
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <KeyboardAvoidingView
          behavior="padding"
          style={styles.textBoxContainerContainer}
          keyboardVerticalOffset={keyboardVerticalOffset}
        >
          <View style={styles.textBoxContainer}>
            <TextBoxMA
              style={styles.textBox}
              placeholder={Strings.USERNAME_PLACEHOLDER}
              value={this.state.userName}
              onChangeText={this.handleTextChange("userName")}
              valid={this.fieldIsValid("userName")}
            />
            {this.renderError("userName")}
          </View>
          <View style={styles.textBoxContainer}>
            <MobileNumberInput
              value={this.state.originalMobile}
              valueChanged={this.handleTextChange("originalMobile")}
              placeholder={Strings.ORIGINAL_MOBILE_PHONE_PLACEHOLDER}
              valid={this.fieldIsValid("originalMobile")}
            />
            {this.renderError("originalMobile")}
          </View>
        </KeyboardAvoidingView>
      </View>
    );
  }

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    padding: 20
  },
  textBoxContainerContainer: {
    flex: 4,
    justifyContent: "flex-end"
  },
  textBoxContainer: {
    height: 40,
    marginBottom: 20
  },
  validationError: {
    fontSize: 12,
    color: "red",
    fontWeight: "bold",
    paddingTop: 3
  }
});
```

The `{this.renderError("originalMobile")}` portion is responsible for rendering an error text. 
I put it there to get a small red warning just under the text box. But the warning stretches to inside mobile number component while the username warning is displayed correctly. Here's the output:

[image]

I've tried wrapping the error Text inside another View, didn't help. Wrapped the container View inside the MobileNumberInput component into yet another View with explicit flex-direction ="column". It didn't help either. I even changed the flex-direction of that container View to "column" just to see what would happen. But it didn't have any effect either. As you can see from the screenshot the problem is with the MobileNumberInput component part. The error text for the Username textinput is ok.

And if you wonder what the TextBoxMA looks like, it's just a TextInput component with predefined properties. Here it is:

```
export const TextBoxMA = props => {
  return (
    <TextInput
      secureTextEntry={props.isPassword || false}
      {...props}
      style={[
        props.style,
        styles.textBox,
        Platform.OS === "ios" ? styles.textBoxIos : styles.textBoxAndroid,
        !props.valid ? styles.invalidTextBox : ""
      ]}
    />
  );
};
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  textBox: {
    height: 40,
    borderColor: "gray",
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 5,
    padding: 5
  },
  invalidTextBox: {
    borderColor: "red"
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've set your input height to 40, but then the View with style `styles.textBoxContainer` which wraps **both** input and error text, is also set to 40 height, squishing MobileNumberInput in half. You can't visually notice this effect because TextInputs inside MobileNumberInput go outside of the parent

To handle cases like this you need to create one container to wrap TextInputs and another container to wrap the first container and the error text. It's best to not set explicit height for containers but rather set their paddings to get desired size

Comment: Yes, you were absolutely right. As a quick try, I changed the height of the `textBoxContainer` height to 60 and it helped. I'll follow your advice on not setting explicit height for containers.